# Need your Experience in NoSQL Database

Tags: java, mongodb, cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

For my exam in noSQL database, I have to store an HTTP log file into a database.
The example that my professor gave me is in MongoDB, so i must use another DBMS. 
I thought of using Cassandra with a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ApacheRecord (
IP text,
ident text,
http_user text,
time text PRIMARY KEY,
http_method text,
url text,
http_response_code text,
http_response_size text,
referred text,
user_agent text)
WITH compaction = {  'class' : 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'min_threshold' : '5', 'max_threshold' : '31' }
AND caching = {'keys':'ALL'}
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE'
AND gc_grace_seconds = '0';
```

Now, I would like to ask you if this could be a good idea and if there is a parser for JAVA that can analyze String like `"192.168.4.25 - - [22/Dec/2016:16:30:52 +0300] "POST /administrator/index.php HTTP/1.1" 303 382 "http://192.168.4.161/DVWA" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.21""` and return substring like 'IP', 'url', etc.

PS: I tried using hBase, but was unable to start the shell

Hope somebody in the comunity can help me 'cause i have no idea if i'm on the right way and that's my last exam.

In the end, I hope you are all well in this particular period :)

Comment: Why is _everything_ text? Databases, especially distributed ones like Cassandra, rely on log files to store data. These log files are divided into entries. Each entry ideally has a fixed length - this is why typing in databases is so important for both performance and disk performance. Your schema is terrible for both.

Comment: Further, why parse the log file with Java? Just dump the access logs directly there from the webserver!

Comment: it's just an example made to ask you if I'm on the right way

Comment: @BoristheSpider 'cause i have to store log's data into my keyspace in cassandra

Comment: Not sure what that’s in response to. You need to think about data types - e.g could time perhaps be a ... date? Perhaps IP address is a 32bit integer? Is there a maximum size of the method field? Could it be an enumeration even? Response code - is that numeric? How about response size? Finally, you have completely ignored the requirements for Cassandra to partition data - without a sensible key structure you will quickly crash Cassandra as the number of records increases.

Comment: Quite a lot of reading in order I’m afraid - perhaps start with the Datastax basic tutorials. e.g. https://www.datastax.com/blog/2015/02/basic-rules-cassandra-data-modeling

Comment: thank you very much, i will start from the datastax tutorial